# Drinking alcohol after work

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an English word for a regular alcohol drinking after work? What is an English word for an alcoholic who drinks after work?

Comment: (1) The "after-work drink" has a million and a half hits on Google. (2) An alcoholic.

Comment: This sounds like 80% of the *Brits* I work with.

Answer (score 3):

In the USA, the period right after work (but before dinner) in which alcoholic beverages may be consumed at an establishment set up for that purpose is often referred to as [Happy Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_hour). Many bars have reduced prices on some or all of their drinks during this period.

You will also often hear "time to leave work and go drinking" referred to as [beer-thirty](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beer%20thirty&defid=1245344)

Comment: I always said happy hour is that time after work where you get to have a relaxing drink and it costs about $1 less than otherwise.  Sad hour is right before work when you have a drink that costs about $1 more than otherwise that stresses you out...and it was invented by Starbucks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [after work drinking](http://www.cosmopolitan.co.uk/body/after-work-drinking-danger) and [after work drinker](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=pN-pEKPtMPIC&pg=RA6-PA24-IA5&lpg=RA6-PA24-IA5&dq=%22after+work+drinkers+in+the%22&source=bl&ots=GBXQwu4rA-&sig=lJ8eZwB7N05y0_S1kRCjqMcoPjU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=sE9UU-CvEYGfO5bygYgB&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22after%20work%20drinkers%20in%20the%22&f=false).

> [The review said peer-group pressure could encourage teetotalers to drink in workplaces with after-work drinking cultures.](http://www.bluelight.org/vb/threads/462632-Combat-alcoholism-in-workplace-study)

Comment: Neither of those are answers to the OP. Also, how do those ngram/google book links support a definition? (neither of those do so in particular anyway).

Answer (score 1):

**[Social drinker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/social+drinker)** can serve for one who drinks after work.

But the best word for an alcoholic who drinks after work is ... **alcoholic**!

Answer (score 1):

In Australia it is a "knock-off drink".
Often drunk by a "piss-pot".